# Multiple form values in one react recoil atom override each other

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, recoiljs

Is there any way to hold multiple form input values in one React Recoil atom? I keep trying to add 2 form field values, but they just override each other.

I have a registration form which has 2 fields; email and phone.

My (simplified) form component looks like so;

```js
import { atom, useSetRecoilState, useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';

const registerAtom = atom({
    key: 'register',
    default: [],
});

function Registration() {
    const setEmail = useSetRecoilState(registerAtom);
    const email = useRecoilValue(registerAtom);

    const setPhone = useSetRecoilState(registerAtom);
    const phone = useRecoilValue(registerAtom);

    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <input name="email" type="text" className="form-control" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email Address" />
                <input name="phone" type="text" className="form-control" value={phone} onChange={e => setPhone(e.target.value)} placeholder="Phone Number" />
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are certain that you will never need to read or write the email and phone states independently, a simple approach is to use a single atom with an object value (this is equivalent to using React's `useState` hook with an object value):

```js
import {atom} from 'recoil';

const contactInfoState = atom({
  key: 'contactInfo',
  default: {
    email: '',
    phone: '',
  },
});
```

Then, use like this (updating the entire object every time):

```jsx
import {useRecoilState} from 'recoil';

function Registration () {
  const [{email, phone}, setContactInfo] = useRecoilState(contactInfoState);
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={ev => setContactInfo({email: ev.target.value, phone})}
        placeholder="Email Address"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={phone}
        onChange={ev => setContactInfo({email, phone: ev.target.value})}
        placeholder="Phone Number"
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

However, the idiomatic way to do this (and where Recoil becomes more powerful) is composition of [`atom`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/atom)s using a [`selector`](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/selector/), which can provide a way for reading and writing the values together (just like in the example above), yet still allows for reading and writing them independently using their atoms:

```js
import {atom, DefaultValue, selector} from 'recoil';

const emailState = atom({
  key: 'email',
  default: '',
});

const phoneState = atom({
  key: 'phone',
  default: '',
});

const contactInfoState = selector({
  key: 'contactInfo',
  get: ({get}) => {
    // get values from individual atoms:
    const email = get(emailState);
    const phone = get(phoneState);
    // then combine into desired shape (object) and return:
    return {email, phone};
  },
  set: ({set}, value) => {
    // in a Reset action, the value will be DefaultValue (read more in selector docs):
    if (value instanceof DefaultValue) {
      set(emailState, value);
      set(phoneState, value);
      return;
    }
    // otherwise, update individual atoms from new object state:
    set(emailState, value.email);
    set(phoneState, value.phone);
  },
});
```

Here's a complete and self-contained example in a snippet, which you can run on this page to verify that it works:

> Note: It uses the UMD versions of `React`, `ReactDOM`, and `Recoil`, so they are exposed globally using those names instead of using `import` statements.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/recoil@0.5.2/umd/recoil.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.3/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="react">

const {
  atom,
  DefaultValue,
  RecoilRoot,
  selector,
  useRecoilValue,
  useSetRecoilState,
} = Recoil;

const emailState = atom({
  key: 'email',
  default: '',
});

const phoneState = atom({
  key: 'phone',
  default: '',
});

const contactInfoState = selector({
  key: 'contactInfo',
  get: ({get}) => {
    const email = get(emailState);
    const phone = get(phoneState);
    return {email, phone};
  },
  set: ({set}, value) => {
    if (value instanceof DefaultValue) {
      set(emailState, value);
      set(phoneState, value);
      return;
    }
    set(emailState, value.email);
    set(phoneState, value.phone);
  },
});

function Registration () {
  const {email, phone} = useRecoilValue(contactInfoState);
  const setEmail = useSetRecoilState(emailState);
  const setPhone = useSetRecoilState(phoneState);
  
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={ev => setEmail(ev.target.value)}
        placeholder="Email Address"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={phone}
        onChange={ev => setPhone(ev.target.value)}
        placeholder="Phone Number"
      />
    </form>
  )
}

function DisplayState () {
  const email = useRecoilValue(emailState);
  const phone = useRecoilValue(phoneState);
  return (
    <pre>
      <code>{JSON.stringify({email, phone}, null, 2)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
}

function Example () {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <Registration />
      <DisplayState />
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Ohhh that works really well, and i didnt know about the selector .. basically a getter and setter in something like PHP ... Thank you very much

Comment: is it possible to just view the values from another component though?

Comment: @CodeSauce If by "view", you mean "read/access" then yes, that's demonstrated in the `DisplayState` component in the snippet, via the `useRecoilValue` hook.

Comment: Oh my bad, that works a treat ... Thanks again, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `atom` has a single value `register` holds an array at the beginning, and later be assigned with the values of the inputs.

Both `input`s set the state of the atom `registerAtom`, makes it override each other.

What you need to do is holding an object as a value for `register`, that has two keys: `email` and `phone`. Then, you can update each key with the relevant value from the specific `input` that has changed.

So. instead of:

```
const registerAtom = atom({
    key: 'register',
    default: [],
});
```

Create this `atom`:

```
const registerAtom = atom({
    key: 'register',
    default: {
        email: '',
        phone: ''
    },
});
```

This created the object with initial values of empty strings for `email` and `phone`.

Now you define the `set` functions like this:

```
const setRegistrationInfo = useSetRecoilState(registerAtom);
const registrationInfo = useRecoilValue(registerAtom);
```

Finally, all you need to do is to change the specific key of the object when you are setting its state. Make sure you are creating a new `Object` since you are updating a state and the state expects a new updated object, so we will use `Object.assign`:

```
        <form>
            <input name="email" type="text" className="form-control" value={registrationInfo.email} onChange={e => setRegistrationInfo(Object.assign(registrationInfo, {email: e.target.value}))} placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input name="phone" type="text" className="form-control" value={registrationInfo.phone} onChange={e => setRegistrationInfo(Object.assign(registrationInfo, {phone: e.target.value}))} placeholder="Phone Number" />
        </form>
```

Final code:

```
import { atom, useSetRecoilState, useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';

const registerAtom = atom({
    key: 'register',
    default: {
        email: '',
        phone: ''
    },
});

function Registration() {

    const setRegistrationInfo = useSetRecoilState(registerAtom);
    const registrationInfo = useRecoilValue(registerAtom);

    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <input name="email" type="text" className="form-control" value={registrationInfo.email} onChange={e => setRegistrationInfo(Object.assign(registrationInfo, {email: e.target.value}))} placeholder="Email Address" />
                <input name="phone" type="text" className="form-control" value={registrationInfo.phone} onChange={e => setRegistrationInfo(Object.assign(registrationInfo, {phone: e.target.value}))} placeholder="Phone Number" />
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Using `setRegistrationInfo(Object.assign(registrationInfo, ...))` is mutating the (read-only) Recoil state in this example. This is a bug in production and throws an exception in development.