# Using recoil selector to filter component data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I feel like i've read so many examples/docs and watched videos but i can't get my head around using selectors with recoil. Maybe i'm just having a bad day cause i don't think it's that hard.

This is where i'm at...

lets say i have data like:

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "wiggles",
    type: "cat",
    age: "244",
  },
  {
    name: "wobbles",
    type: "dog",
    age: "55",
  },
  {
    name: "flobbles",
    type: "dog",
    age: "98",
  },
];
```

in my index i have:

```
export const typeFilterState = atom({
   key: 'typeFilterState',
   default: '',
});
const UserPage: NextPage<Props> = ({data}) => {

const [typeFilter, setTypeFilter] = useRecoilState(typeFilterState);

return(
<select onChange={(e) => setLeagueFilter(e.target.value)}>
<option value='cat'>Cat</option>
<option value='dog'>Dog</option>
<option value='elephant'>Elephant</option>
</select>

{
  data.map((d) => (
    <DataComponent data={d} />
  ))
}
)};
```

DataComponent would be like:

```
const DataComponent: FunctionComponent<Animals> = ({data}) => {
return (
   <Text>{data.name}</Text>
   <Text>{data.type}</Text>
   <Text>{data.age}</Text>
)
};
```

I want it so if users select `cat` it only shows data with cats, but also to show ALL data if nothing is selected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your `<select>` `onChange` function:

```js
// <select onChange={(e) => setLeagueFilter(e.target.value)}>
<select onChange={(e) => setTypeFilter(e.target.value)}>
```

Just filter the array based on the `typeFilter` value before mapping as components:

```js
// data.map((d) => (
//   <DataComponent data={d} />
// ))

data
  .filter(({type}) => {
    // nothing selected yet, keep all:
    if (!typeFilter.trim()) return true;
    // else keep if item.type equals filter:
    return type === typeFilter;
  })
  .map((d) => (
    <DataComponent data={d} />
  ))
```

Comment: You don't need a `selector` here, but if you find the docs confusing and want a breakdown/example, you can see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69967988/438273), and hopefully it'll help make things clear.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the typo, I just quickly wrote this example to show what I was trying to achieve. Ahh well I figured if I was using recoil for sharing state I should try and learn `selector` too. The example in the docs shows it being used to filter a to-do list. But regardless your answer solves my problem :) thanks the the reply!